# AuthenticationContext not compiling extracting Azure token?

Tags: azure, authentication

I am trying to connect to Power BI using rest as per the instructions in the link below

[Power BI Rest Tutorial](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmtechnical/archive/2017/10/30/refresh-powerbi-reports-using-c-and-web-api)

However, the line below does not work

`var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityURL, false);`

I get the error 'AuthenticationContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

I am using v3.17.1 of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

even when I try to downgrade the package I still get this error

Has anyone come across this?

The tutorial is very recent

Paul

Comment: I've just tried replicating your issue but everything works correctly for me. Are you sure `AuthenticationContext` is referencing `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`? There is a possibility you might be referencing `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` or `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` which do not provide the constructor you are after.

Comment: That was it thanks!!